# java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method getEmployee(String) is undefined for the type EmployeeDAO

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am using Eclipse IDE to run my Maven project which uses REST to execute CRUD. The app runs on Tomcat Server, but when I go to `http://localhost:8080/RESTfulCRUD/rest/employees/E01` I get the error above. It says that the methods are undefined, even though they are in fact. The classes are the following:

> EmployeeService

```
@Path("employees")
public class EmployeeService {

    // URI:
    // /contextPath/servletPath/employees
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public List<Employee> getEmployees_JSON() {
        List<Employee> listOfCountries = EmployeeDAO.getAllEmployees();
        return listOfCountries;
    }

    // URI:
    // /contextPath/servletPath/employees/{empNo}
    @GET
    @Path("/{empNo}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathParam("empNo") String empNo) {
        return EmployeeDAO.getEmployee(empNo);
    }

    // URI:
    // /contextPath/servletPath/employees
    @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Employee addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        return EmployeeDAO.addEmployee(emp);
    }

    // URI:
    // /contextPath/servletPath/employees
    @PUT
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public Employee updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
        return EmployeeDAO.updateEmployee(emp);
    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/{empNo}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
    public void deleteEmployee(@PathParam("empNo") String empNo) {
        EmployeeDAO.deleteEmployee(empNo);
    }

}
```

> EmployeeDAO

```
import org.o7planning.RESTfulCRUD.model.Employee;

public class EmployeeDAO {

    private static final Map<String, Employee> empMap = new HashMap<String, Employee>();

    static {
        initEmps();
    }

    private static void initEmps() {
        Employee emp1 = new Employee("E01", "Smith", "Clerk");
        Employee emp2 = new Employee("E02", "Allen", "Salesman");
        Employee emp3 = new Employee("E03", "Jones", "Manager");

        empMap.put(emp1.getEmpNo(), emp1);
        empMap.put(emp2.getEmpNo(), emp2);
        empMap.put(emp3.getEmpNo(), emp3);
    }

    public static Employee getEmployee(String empNo) {
        return empMap.get(empNo);
    }

    public static Employee addEmployee(Employee emp) {
        empMap.put(emp.getEmpNo(), emp);
        return emp;
    }

    public static Employee updateEmployee(Employee emp) {
        empMap.put(emp.getEmpNo(), emp);
        return emp;
    }

    public static void deleteEmployee(String empNo) {
        empMap.remove(empNo);
    }

    public static List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        Collection<Employee> c = empMap.values();
        List<Employee> list = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        list.addAll(c);
        return list;
    }

    List<Employee> list;


}
```

There is one more class Employee, but there is no problem with it. Any ideas about the problem?

Comment: Maybe it is searching for a non `static` method.

Comment: @Selaron I'm not sure about that, cause I've deleted static from everywhere and still get mistakes. The source code is here [https://o7planning.org/en/11207/simple-crud-example-with-java-restful-web-service]